# How to solve operator does not exist error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

For table value BENMASTDTL_PAYEE_MOB_NUM am getting error like

> operator does not exist: bigint = text

But I have declared its value in table as bigint.

```
ELSIF P_TRANSFER_TYPE = '7M' THEN
      
        EXECUTE 'SELECT BENMASTDTL_BEN_CODE FROM BENMASTDTL WHERE BENMASTDTL_ENTITY_CODE =$1 AND BENMASTDTL_CUSTOMER_CODE =$2 AND
                            BENMASTDTL_PAYEE_MOB_NUM =$3 AND BENMASTDTL_PAYEE_MMID=$4 AND BENMASTDTL_PAYEE_MMID_TYPE=$5 LIMIT 1'
          INTO STRICT W_BENMASTDTL_BEN_CODE
          USING P_ENTITY_CODE, P_CUST_CODE, P_BEN_MOB_NUM, P_BEN_MMID, P_BEN_MMID_TYPE;
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Use comparable datatypes or cast your data to something useful

Comment: Unrelated, but: the dynamic SQL is totally useless here.

Comment: You probably need to declare the parameter `P_BEN_MOB_NUM` with the type `bigint`. But as you have not shown the whole function, it's really hard to tell.